# How would you setModel() to the player entity for a Minecraft bukkit plugin

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

So basically I am creating a magic wand plugin for bukkit. I was wondering how you can set a players model.

For example, if I right click it will turn me into a chicken. I have no idea on how to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are numerous plugins providing this functionality, both stabdalone and offering an API as well. They include:

- http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/idisguise/
- http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/disguisecraft/
- http://www.spigotmc.org/resources/libs-disguises.81/

==Edit==

Here's an example of using DisguiseCraft:

Before starting, make sure to add the latest jarfile to your IDE's external dependencies.

First, you need to add a dependency into your plugin.yml:

```
depend: [DisguiseCraft]
```

The brackets are needed since it is an array

Second, when your plugin is enabled, you need to acquire the instance of the API class.

```
DisguiseCraftAPI api;
@Override public void onEnable() {
    this.api = DisguiseCraft.getAPI();
}
```

Then, to disguise, you can use

```
Player player = // ...
Disguise disguise = new Disguise(this.api.newEntityID(), player.getName(), DisguiseType.Player);
this.api.disguisePlayer(player, disguise);
```

All disguises can be found here: http://build.yu8.me:8080/job/DisguiseCraft/ws/javadocs/pgDev/bukkit/DisguiseCraft/disguise/DisguiseType.html

Make sure to check if the player is already disguised, you use the change player disguise instead of the set player disguise.

Comment: Hey there, xTrollxDudex, thank you so much for the reply. By any chance, would people using this plugin require any other jar files other than the actual plugin itself to run this on their server? I'm just curious, because I've not actually tested this yet, I am going to be testing it later on.

Comment: Well, you can certainly include the jar file in your compiled plugin yourself, or you can have the user download your plugin in addition to DisguiseCraft as well.